# One django template not picking CSS, other templates are fine

Tags: css, django-templates

I have two django templates in my one folder. The template for the url `localhost:8000/people` picks CSS correctly which is located at `/m/css/style.css`

The other template for the url `localhost:8000/people/some-name` in the same folder is trying to retrieve CSS from `people/m/css/style.css`

Why is this second template not picking CSS like the first one?

My erring second template is like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_title %}{{ entry.name }} | {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}    

{% block main %}
<h1>{{ entry.name }}</h1>
{{ entry.body|linebreaks }}

{% endblock main %}
```

As you can see there's nothing in the template that could cause problem.

Comment: Can you show us the code in `base.html`? Specifically, the `<head>` section. Also, can you include from your `settings.py`, how you're setting `SITE_STATIC_MEDIA`? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your templates are looking for a stylesheet located at `../m/css/style.css`.  That's why the template in `/people` works - `/people/../m/css/style.css` refers to `/m/css/style.css`.  However, /people/some-name/../m/css/style.css`refers to`people/m/css/style.css`, not the desired address.

Make sure the templates are looking for `/m/css/style.css` - emphasis on the very first `/` character.